# What its wrong with this for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want to print n times that user want and count how many times it is printing for that reason the 'i' variable. What its wrong with the code.

```
echo How many want to prints?
set /p numPrints=
set i=1
FOR /L %%A IN (%i%,1,numPrints) DO (
echo Hello World
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR /L %%A IN (%i%,1,%numPrints%) DO (
```

`%var%` refers to the value of a variable `var`